# Python 3.4 : How to populate Pandas multi-indexed DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created a 2-d dataframe with the following code:

```
output = OrderedDict((i,j) for i,*j in [data[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(data),4)])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(output, orient='index')

print(df)
```

Which gives the following output.

## output

```
                                               0         1         2
Total Revenue                           31821000  30871000  29904000
Cost of Revenue                         16447000  16106000  15685000
Gross Profit                            15374000  14765000  14219000
Research Development                     1770000   1715000   1634000
Selling General and Administrative       6469000   6384000   6102000
Non Recurring                                  0         0         0
Others                                         0         0         0
Total Operating Expenses                       0         0         0
Operating Income or Loss                 7135000   6666000   6483000
Total Other Income/Expenses Net            33000     41000     39000
Earnings Before Interest And Taxes       7168000   6707000   6522000
Interest Expense                          142000    145000    171000
Income Before Tax                        7026000   6562000   6351000
Income Tax Expense                       2028000   1841000   1840000
Minority Interest                         -42000    -62000    -67000
Net Income From Continuing Ops           4956000   4659000   4444000
Discontinued Operations                        0         0         0
Extraordinary Items                            0         0         0
Effect Of Accounting Changes                   0         0         0
Other Items                                    0         0         0
Net Income                               4956000   4659000   4444000
Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments          0         0         0
Net Income Applicable To Common Shares   4956000   4659000   4444000
```

I would like to take the information from above and instead of creating its own dataframe I would like to populate the MMM IncomeStatement field in the fololwing MultiIndex Dataframe

```
with open('/home/a73nk-xce/Documents/Python/SP500_list/stockChar/ticker.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
        ticker = row

fin_state = ['IncomeStatement', 'BalanceSheet', 'CashFlows']

iterables = [ticker, fin_state]

fin_data = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['Ticker', 'Financials'])

print(fin_data)
```

## Output

```
MMM     IncomeStatement
        BalanceSheet   
        CashFlows      
ABT     IncomeStatement
        BalanceSheet   
        CashFlows      
ABBV    IncomeStatement
        BalanceSheet   
        CashFlows      
ACN     IncomeStatement
        BalanceSheet   
        CashFlows      
ACE     IncomeStatement
        BalanceSheet   
        CashFlows
```

## CSV file:

```
,0,1,2
Total Revenue,182795000,170910000,156508000
Cost of Revenue,112258000,106606000,87846000
Gross Profit,70537000,64304000,68662000
Research Development,6041000,4475000,3381000
Selling General and Administrative,11993000,10830000,10040000
Non Recurring,0,0,0
Others,0,0,0
Total Operating Expenses,0,0,0
Operating Income or Loss,52503000,48999000,55241000
Total Other Income/Expenses Net,980000,1156000,522000
Earnings Before Interest And Taxes,53483000,50155000,55763000
Interest Expense,0,0,0
Income Before Tax,53483000,50155000,55763000
Income Tax Expense,13973000,13118000,14030000
Minority Interest,0,0,0
Net Income From Continuing Ops,39510000,37037000,41733000
Discontinued Operations,0,0,0
Extraordinary Items,0,0,0
Effect Of Accounting Changes,0,0,0
Other Items,0,0,0
Net Income,39510000,37037000,41733000
Preferred Stock And Other Adjustments,0,0,0
Net Income Applicable To Common Shares,39510000,37037000,41733000
```

Comment: @DSM - What do you think?

Comment: Can you upload a sample data file?

Comment: All of that data is being parsed cleaned up and put into a dataframe from yahooFinance there isn't a datafile for it

Comment: @JianxunLi do you think that it would be more wise to use panel functionality and populate a panel with a dict of dataframes?  Or would you recommend sticking with a multiindex?

Comment: Could you please use pd.DataFrame.to_csv() to produce a csv file and upload it here? Many thanks.

Comment: @JianxunLi csv loaded

Comment: I think Multi-level index DataFrame structure would be sufficient in your case. Using stack() and unstack() to reshape the dataset for further analysis.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80895/discussion-between-aran-freel-and-jianxun-li).